# What do we call models that output probabilistic scores vs. models that output non-probabilistic scores?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, svm

In machine learning -- specifically in binary classification -- there are models that output a probability for each data-point fed to the model. For example, a logistic regression could take some patient's data as input and output the **probability** that he/she has cancer.

There are also models that output scores (could be outside of $(0,1)$ range), such as support vector machines. These models could take the same input data but output a **score** (positive or negative) that doesn't have a direct probabilistic interpretation.

I'm wondering how we should differentiate these types of models, specifically in name.

For example, we can differentiate models as being either *Instance-Based* (K-Nearest Neighbours) or *Model-Based* (linear regression). 
Is there a similar naming convention for models that output **probabilites** vs. models that output **scores**?